# Oracle Query - Filter and Limit in two tables using JOIN

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-query-store

I am facing an issue in Oracle Query to achieve the following use case,

Consider I have two tables :

```
Table 1 : product
     productId - Integer - primaryKey
     productName - Varchar 

Table 2 : product_sequence
     productId - Integer - primaryKey
     sequenceId - Integer - primaryKey 
     orderId - Integer
     orderName - Varchar
```

product table has 1000 entries and product_sequence table has 10K entries

**Requirement** :

1. (paginate) fetch the entries from 0 to 100 / 100 to 200 / etc., in the product table
2. Distinct count of productId for showing the pagination in UI (check the sample query below)
3. Filter by 'productName' in 'product' table and 'orderName' in 'product_sequence' table

**Query (tried)** :

```
SELECT
  p.productId, p.productName, ps.orderId, ps.orderName, 
  COUNT(distinct p.productId) OVER () AS TOTAL 
FROM (
  select * 
  from product 
  OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
 ) p 
JOIN product_sequence ps on p.productId=ps.productId 
WHERE ps.orderId IN ('12','13','14');
```

NOTE : the above query will work in Oracle, But the issue is

**Expected**:
Return 100 entries from 'product' table with mapped entries in the 'product_sequence' table

**Actual** :
It first LIMITS 100 entries in product and then filter the orderId so the number of entries returned is reduced from 100 to lesser number
**I agree my query is not correct**: It first LIMIT by 100 in 'product' table in subquery and then goes for filter in second table which reduces the count

**Could some one help me with the query for this please? Anyhelp is appreciated.**
If my question is not clear, Let me know, I can explain with more info.

Comment: Pagination without ordering makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the `OFFSET` and `FETCH`  clauses to the outer query, something like this:

```
SELECT q.productId, q.productName, q.orderId, q.orderName,
       COUNT(distinct p.productId) OVER () AS TOTAL
FROM ( SELECT * FROM product p JOIN product_sequence ps ON p.productId = ps.productId
       WHERE ps.orderId IN ('12','13','14') ) q
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

To get 100 rows per page "after filtering" you'll need to find all the `productid` values first, then process the main query.

For example:

```
select
  p.productid, p.productname, ps.orderid, ps.orderName,
  count(distinct p.productid) over() as total
from product p
join product_sequence ps on p.productid = ps.productid
where ps.orderid in ('12','13','14')
and p.productid in (
  select *
  from (
    select distinct p.productid
    from product p
    join product_sequence ps on p.productid = ps.productid
    where p.productname like '%theremin%' -- filter #1
      and ps.orderid in ('12','13','14')  -- filter #2
  ) x
  order by productid
  offset 300 rows -- get the 4th page
  fetch first 100 rows only -- page size set to 100 rows
)
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db21fdd3ac59d85702bff692b7187e68).